# Value is truncated from a textbox when you navigate from a number field in android 4.0.4 ICS in phonegap app

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, phone-number

I have two fields one with type "tel" & other with type "text" in my phonegap application.

Problem:

I enter some value in text field suppose "abcdefghijkl"

Now I enter some value in number field suppose `12345` and click on the text field.

The value in text field is truncated to "fghijkl". Number of digits u enter in num field, equal number of characters from text field are erased.

This issue only occurs in Android 4.0.4 on a Samsung galaxy S3 mobile, I have also tesed on Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.4 where it works fine. Other android versions also works fine.

Any inputs/help is appreciated.

CODE:

```
<input type="tel" class="ui-shadow-inset" id="telNumber" placeholder="NUMBER" tabindex="1"/>
<input type="text" class="ui-shadow-inset" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" tabindex="2"/>
```

Comment: Do you have some fancy CSS attributes on that element? http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-user-modify If yes, remove it. I had REALLY strange bugs with this attribute set.

Comment: I tried keeping the code as simple as below (no css no js, simple html) The problem still persists :(

Comment: `<input type="tel" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
 <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Password" />`